# Redistribute RIP tables in quagga

Tags: routing, quagga, rip

Apparently the command for that is `redistribute connected`. Where do I input it? I tried it in the telnet interface, but it's not recognised.

Answer (score 1):

Connect to ripd daemon

```
telnet localhost ripd
```

If still not working or doesn't recognize ripd try

```
telnet localhost 2602

enable
```

Then go in configuration mode

```
host# conf t
```

Then go into rip configuration

```
host# router rip
```

and run command

```
host#(conf-router) redistribute connected
```

Now press Ctrl+Z and save configuration

```
host# write
```

Regards

Comment: `vtysh -c redistribute connected` => unknown command. And I'm using the ripd daemon, not bgpd.

Comment: Fixed. see now!

Comment: Sorry, you misundertood; I can login to the telnet interface just fine. I `enable` it, but then the redistribute command is not recognised (it's not `list`ed either).

Comment: Did you forgot about configuration mode ?

Comment: Still an unknown command in the config mode, still doesn't show up on the `list`. Also, doesn't this just save the settings to the config file? How would I put it there manually? Just putting `redistribute connected` raises an error when starting the daemon.

Comment: What OS do you are running? What version of quagga ?

Comment: Running Debian, Quagga 0.99.5.

Answer (score 0):

You could add it to your ripd configuration file which is in `/etc/quaga/ripd.conf`. By the way you should have ripd service enabled and started…